# Assign integer value of choice to True / False values in a boolean other than 0 and 1

Tags: python, numpy, boolean

Is it possible to assign integer/ float values other than default 1 and 0 to the boolean **True** and **False** in array?

By default **True** converts to 1 and **False** to 0 from what I know. However when I try to assign '5.0' to **True** from a 2d array dtype=bool, the output still gives **True** and not the assigned integer value

```
#main_arr is a 3d array
main_arr = self.predictor(image)["instances"].pred_masks
#Taking the slice from 3d array based on 1st dimension
arr = np.asarray(main_arr[0,:,:])
#finding the non zero elements
row, col = np.nonzero(arr)
#assigning values to non zero elements
arr[row, col] = 5.0
print("The Non Zero value of element is :", arr[row[0]][col[0]])
```

The output is still **True**

```
The Non Zero value of element is : True
```

Whereas I would like to see something like

```
The Non Zero value of element is : 5.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `dtype` of `arr` is boolean, when you make assignments within that array, it is being cast to match the `dtype`. You need an array with the appropriate `dtype` to do this:

```
arr = arr.astype(np.float64)
arr[row, col] = 5.0
```

Comment: Works like a charm. You a life saver. Would appreciate if I could upvote for the question. Already too low on votes to ask a question.